# Slow csv writing with python3 compared to python2 with pandas to_csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, export-to-csv

Can anyone clarify why is writing to a csv file using pandas method to_csv way slower when using python interpreter 3 instead of 2? From pandas documentation I found that default encoding with python3 = utf-8 and with python2 = ascii and this was the only difference I found. Still it does not explain the big difference in time, since even if I give the encoding argument encoding = 'ascii' in python3 to the to_csv, the results are still way slower.

I am using spyder with anaconda and my dataframe is approx. 800 thousand rows with 6 columns, with dtypes : datetime64[ns], float64, int64, float64, float64, float64.

In both python environments I have pandas 0.22.0 version installed. Numpy versions are also the same, them being 1.14.0. I am also running these scripts in Windows 10.

With python-2.7:

```
start = timer()   
df.to_csv(path, index = False, date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
time = timer() - start
87.6402205

start = timer()   
df.to_csv(path, index = False, date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', encoding = 'utf-8')
time = timer() - start
118.808225
```

With pyton-3.5

```
start = timer()   
df.to_csv(path, index = False, date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
time = timer() - start
149.52978580000004

start = timer()   
df.to_csv(path, index = False, date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', encoding = 'ascii')
time = timer() - start
138.72526400000015
```

What is the reason for this? Do I need to give a specific float format in python3 which is different by default than when using python2?

Comment: I've also had issues with `to_csv` taking extreme amounts of time with no apparent explanation.